# Manually render log template used in .NET logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, logging, ilogger

In .NET one logs like so:

```cs
logger.LogInformation("Hello {What}", "World");
```

Which renders:

```
Hello World
```

I need to manually render that template (the upstream code is not mine and I can't redesign). I can't use `string.Format(message, args)` because that is not meant for structured logging.

Is there a method somewhere in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` (or elsewhere) which would allow me to do this? Something with the same signature as the logging methods:

```cs
string Render(string message, params object[] args);
```

Comment: I'm curious why you need this? Are you just trying to format what goes into the log? Which log provider are you using?

Comment: For what logger? For me thats to a certain degree implementation detail of the logger registered for the ILogger interface. I mean i may now a Logger that will take the data in the form you hope (i actually don't) but will put it in a database and that you maybe not want.

Comment: We have a logger adapter that passes the logs into the M.E.Logging library, but at that point also need to "tap" it for other uses. If the code were mine I'd redesign to use Serilog which has logging wrappers/adapters, but in a production system that's not typically possible - you just need to find a way. So given the message and args that would go into M.E.Loggging, I need to render it and redirect that somewhere. Frankly I'm surprised there's no exposed convenience method that simply renders the template. I'll guess I have to reinvent the wheel and do some ugly string handling.

Comment: If you have already code in between and your answer to the answer below is that you need  string.Format to work or something close to that could you simply replace the named parameter with its position in that in between code?  So in your code example simply replace "what" with "0" in the underlying infrastructure code you have?

Comment: @Ralf Assuming the position is always dependable (I'll need to check), that is actually a very simple solution... I'll give it a try, thanks Ralf.

Comment: Your assumed surface of the render method does not allow anything else then going for position or you would need Key/Value pairs as argument to tell "this arg is for the what placeholder".

Comment: @Ralf I used that idea and added an answer below, thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. All of the code converting message templates into log messages is internal. You can maybe copy/get inspiration from the `LogValuesFormatter` class in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` namespace doesn't expose anything useful in this regard. So I had to write my own:

```cs
public string RenderLogMessage(string message, params object[] args)
{
  var pattern = @"(.*?{)(\w+?.+?)(}.*)";
  for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
  {
    message = Regex.Replace(message, pattern, $"$1 {i} $3", RegexOptions.None);
  }
  message = message.Replace("{ ", "{").Replace(" }", "}");

  return string.Format(message, args);
}
```

For my use case it assumes the template and args are correct (because they are also used in `logger.LogX(message, args)`). For a different use case, it would be wise to add error handling.